# Google Maps Directions API getting error

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-api-2, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

i am using react native maps to show direction between two location , i used MapViewDirections for that ,

i have created GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY and added in app but i am warning and not able to see direction in map . here is code

```
<MapViewDirections
        origin={origin}
        destination={destination}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
      strokeColor="hotpink"

  />
```

`ERROR` :  **MapViewDirections Error: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 1.42.189.121, with empty referer**

Answer (score -1):

Change the Key restrictions in your API to none as shown below:

[image]

Or select IP instead of none and need to add your IP addresses.